# Make colbacklower transparent

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

Am trying to create a tcolorbox with biskin color, but I want both sides transparent, here is my code:

```
\newtcolorbox{mysolbox}{
standard jigsaw,
breakable,
sidebyside,
sidebyside align=top,
skin=bicolor,
boxsep=1mm,
left=8mm,
right=1mm,
top=1mm,
%colback=orange!30,
opacityback=0,
opacityframe=0,
colframe=black!5,
arc=15pt,
sharp corners,
%rounded corners=south,
overlay={
\node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {\bf\strut {\color{cyan} KCPE\examyear~}{\color{black}No.~\theqnumber}}; 
\path[ultra thick,fill=red!80!black] (title@aux.south west)--(title@aux.south east) 
to[out=90, in=270] ([yshift=5mm]title@aux.east)--
(title@aux.center|-frame.north) -| 
(frame.west) |- (title@aux.west)[sharp corners] -- cycle;  
\node[rotate=90, anchor=north west, inner sep=2mm, text=white] (title@aux) at (frame.south west) {\bf\strut {\color{white} KCPE 2019~}{\color{black}No.~1}}; 
},
%colbacklower=white,
%\kvtcb@opacitybacklower=0,
opacitybacklower=0,
}
```

`opacitybacklower=0` seems not to work. Give me a better solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? How is `\examyear` defined? And the counter `qnumber`?

Comment: Your code with `overlay` commented shows a completely transparent box

Comment: Let me input the working code. Meanwhile am using exam class